# Binary operation `==` cannot be applied to type X

Tags: rust, equality

I have a custom type:

```
pub struct PValue {
    pub name: String,
    pub value: Option<serde_json::Value>,
    pub from: Option<String>,
}
pub struct CC {
    pub name: String,
    pub inst_name: String,
    pub pv: Option<Vec<PValue>>,
}

pub struct ComponentRecord {
    config: CC,
    version: String,
}

let cr = ComponentRecord {
        version: "123".to_string(),
        config: CC {
            name: "n123".to_string(),
            instance_name: "inst123".to_string(),
            pv: None,
        },
    };
let newcr = ComponentRecord {
        version: "123".to_string(),
        config: ComponentConfiguration {
            name: "n123".to_string(),
            instance_name: "inst123".to_string(),
            pv: None,
        },
    };
assert_eq!(crgot, cr);
```

Then I got error:

```
error[E0369]: binary operation `==` cannot be applied to type `&ComponentRecord`
  --> src/xxx_test.rs:39:5
   |
39 |     assert_eq!(crgot, cr);
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |     |
   |     ComponentRecord
   |     ComponentRecord
   |
  = note: an implementation of `std::cmp::PartialEq` might be missing for `&ComponentRecord`
```

How could I test two `RecordAnnotation` instance is equal?

I was writing test for that, so I won't mind whether the performance is ok.

In golang, I can use [reflect.DeepEqual](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#DeepEqual) to do that. I hope to find a common way to do in rust.

Comment: What did you try? A simple comparison works well! `record1 == record2`

Comment: In fact, my custom type is more complicated then that, let me modify my question , thanks

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`BTreeMap` implements:

- [Eq](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.BTreeMap.html#impl-Eq) when both key and value types implement `Eq`.
- [PartialEq](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.BTreeMap.html#impl-PartialEq%3CBTreeMap%3CK%2C%20V%3E%3E) when both key and value types implement `PartialEq`.

If all fields of your type implement `PartialEq`, you can easily derive `PartialEq` for the entire struct:

```rust
#[derive(PartialEq)]
pub struct ComponentRecord {
    config: String,
    version: String,
}
```

Then you'll be able to simply use the `==` operator on your maps:

```rust
pub type RecordAnnotation = BTreeMap<String, ComponentRecord>;

fn compare (a: &RecordAnnotation, b: &RecordAnnotation) -> bool {
    a == b
}
```

Comment: how could I implement `Option<Vec<PValue>>` PartialEq?

Comment: I have figured it out, just add PartialEq on top of the type PValue