# binary operation `==` cannot be applied to custom struct

Tags: rust, types

I have this code:

```
use rand::seq::SliceRandom;
use std::ops::Range;

struct Stack {
    settings: bool
}

fn generate_random_value(number: u8, cards: &mut Vec<Stack>) -> Vec<&Stack> {
    let mut overflow = vec![];
    let pos: usize = 2;
    for _ in (Range { start: 0, end: number } ) {
        let card = cards.choose(&mut rand::thread_rng()).unwrap();
        overflow.push(card);
        let elem = cards.iter().position(|&x| &x == card).unwrap();
    };
    return overflow
}

fn main() {
    let stack_one = Stack {
        settings: true
    };

    let stack_two = Stack {
        settings: false
    };

    let mut vector = vec![stack_one, stack_two];
    let _gen_num = generate_random_value(2, &mut vector);
}
```

Why does the error occur? The types are the same; `&Stack` and `&Stack`. How can I get rid of the error?

[Online rust](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=900fa264927b80bf857252930cada195)

Comment: For all custom structs you'll need to either manually implement a trait `PartialEq`, or use `#[derive(PartialEq)]` in front of struct definition to implement it automatically

Comment: Also besides the above, you'll have to compare as `.position(|x| *x == *card)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Binary operation \`==\` cannot be applied to type X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57771512/binary-operation-cannot-be-applied-to-type-x)

Comment: mkrieger1 I don’t understand your question and answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example, you can derive `PartialEq` trait:

```
#[derive(PartialEq)]
struct Stack {
    settings: bool
}
```

In more complex situation, you can overload it:

```
impl PartialEq for Stack {
    fn eq(&self, other: &Self) -> bool {
        ... Your logic ...
    }
}
```